# Code correction suggestion using Java libraries for strings?

Tags: java

I know there is an easier way of making things work to check whether a string is a palindrome or not, but I wanted to try it using library functions and I came up with the code below.

```
public boolean isPalindrome1(String input)
{

    int length = input.length()/2;
    if(input.length()%2!=0)
    {
        length = length + 1;
    }


    return(input.substring(0,length).equals(new StringBuilder(input.substring(length, input.length())).reverse().toString()));
}
```

I'm trying to check whether half the string is equal to the other half's reverse. But it is getting messed up for odd and even lengths. Can someone point corrections in this where it will work for odd, even lengths as well as empty string and string of length = 1.

Comment: Why half?  You won't get any noticeable performance improvements over the whole string (which avoids the odd/even problem)

Comment: But with splitting how will it work ? I will not use the code but am just curious to know how to solve for this case.

Comment: There's no need to solve a hard problem if there's an easier way to do it.  "Solving for this case" in my book is using the simple solution.

Comment: @Phoenix here you go.. look at my answer

Comment: @SomeKittens you should know each and every possible way to solve a problem

Comment: If I know the best way to solve a problem, that's good enough for me.  @HarmeetSingh, do you know every possible way to solve the Knapsack problem?

Comment: @SomeKittens to only know best doesn't make you best, a suggestion.. its life every aspect should be considered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already using reverse(). Why can you not compare the input String with the reverse? Isn't that exactly what you're wanting in the first place? No need to be splitting things in half in a complicated way.

Answer (score 2):

you can:

```
return new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString().equals(input);
```

here you go as you want to know :

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```